# Fetch and display multiple images asynchronously

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and i'm trying to fetch and display some images asynchronously. Here is what i've tried so far,

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++){

  var _image= new Image();
  _image.onload = function(){

    var id= "image".concat(i);                    
    document.getElementById(id).src = this.src;

    };

  _image.src = urls[i]);

}
```

As expected when the `onLoad` event fires `i` does not start from zero, thus images don't display correctly. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: use `for (let i` and that should already do the trick (though I don't see why you use `"image".concat(i)` )

Comment: By their very nature, asynchronous operations started immediately one after another are not guaranteed to finish in the order in which they were started.

Comment: Do you already have the urls and `<img>` with on page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just one global value for `i`, and once all images have been loaded it is probably already set to 10. You could use `let`, which will make your counter scoped. This way, each of your image callbacks will have a copy of the current counter value.

```
for (let i=0; i<10; i++){

  var _image= new Image();
  _image.onload = function(){

    var id= "image".concat(i);                    
    document.getElementById(id).src = this.src;

    };

  _image.src = urls[i]);

}
```

You can read more about that [here](https://wesbos.com/for-of-es6/).

Answer (score 3):

The images are probably displaying out of order for a different reason. When you fetch or display an image asynchronously, each image will take a different amount of time to complete that process.

Imagine for instance that image 4 is huge and image 5 is tiny. Image 5 is likely to be displayed before image 4. **Therefore, I would presume that you are not *fetching* the images out of order, but *displaying* them out of order.**

The easiest solution is to change your display logic or to fetch and display these images sequentially by wrapping each fetch+display in a promise.

Also, you should use for (let i = 0 ...) in your for loop.